# Ninguna aplicacion puede realizar esta opción

Tags: angularjs, ionic, cordova

Anteriormente podia agregar la ruta de una imagen luego de convertirla a `Base64` aun **Input** para luego ser mostrado en un **DIV**, pero luego de un tiempo al tratar ahora de realizar el proceso no me permite realizar dicha acción y me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

[image: imagen]

Antes funcionaba en cualquier equipo, pero ahora no se que puede estar produciendo dicho error. A continuación dejo el código:

```
angular.module('perfilEstudiante', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
    .controller('mostrarPerfilEstu', mostrarPerfilEstu)
    .directive('pickFile', pickFile)
    .factory('obtenerPerfilEstu', obtenerPerfilEstu);


mostrarPerfilEstu.$inject = ['$scope', 'obtenerPerfilEstu'];

function mostrarPerfilEstu($scope, obtenerPerfilEstu, $element) {

    var Perfil, Mes, Periodo_Estu, input, button, evtHandler, dataImage;

    dataImage = localStorage.getItem("imgData");

    if (dataImage === null) {
        $scope.dataImage = "img/profile_icon.png";
    } else {
        $scope.dataImage = "data:image/png;base64," + dataImage;
    }

    $scope.loadImage = function (file) {

        if (file.type.indexOf('image') < 0) {
            $scope.res = "Tipo inválido";
            $scope.$apply();
            return;
        }

        var fReader = new FileReader();

        fReader.onload = function () {

            var data = fReader.result;
            $scope.dataImage = data;
            $scope.res = "";
            $scope.$apply();
            localStorage.setItem("imgData", data.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpe?g);base64,/, ""));

        };

        fReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    };

};

function pickFile() {

    return {

        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            onselected: "&"
        },

        template: '<button class="button button-icon icon ion-plus-round pull-right">' +
        '<input type="file" style="display: none !important">' +
        '</button>',

        link: function ($scope, $element) {
              var input = $element.find('input');
              var button = $element.find('button');

            var evtHandler = function () {
                input[0].click();
            };

            button.on('click', evtHandler)
            input.on('change', function () {
                var file = input[0].files[0];
                $scope.onselected({
                    file: file
                });
            });
        }

    };

};
```

Mi telefono cuenta con la versión de Android 4.2.2

Comment: Estas usando algún plugin de Cordova para que maneje la selección de ficheros? Tengo entendido que el plugin de "`Crosswalk file selection`" puede dar este tipo de problemas. De todos modos, podrías probar simplemente a añadir un atributo `accept` al input file? Si es para imágenes, algo así: `accept="image/"`.

Comment: @frikinside lo pude lograr corregir uso el plugin de la cámara, en vez de tomar una foto agarro una foto de la galeria

Comment: Me alegro de que encontraras la solución ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo pude resolver usando el plugin `$cordovaCamera`, [Enlace del plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/)

#### HTML

```
<div class="list logo-perfil">            
   <div id="res" ng-click="obtenerFoto()">
      <img ng-src="{{data.ImageURI}}" id="myImage" class="image-size" />
   </div>
</div>
```

#### Js

```
angular.module('perfilEstudiante', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
       .controller('mostrarPerfilEstu', mostrarPerfilEstu);

mostrarPerfilEstu.$inject = ['$scope', 'obtenerPerfilEstu', '$cordovaCamera', '$cordovaFile'];

function mostrarPerfilEstu($scope, obtenerPerfilEstu, $cordovaCamera, $cordovaFile, $element) {

    var Perfil, Mes, Periodo_Estu, input, button, evtHandler, dataImage;

    Mes = moment().format('MM');

    if (Mes < 07) {
        Periodo_Estu = "Periodo - I";
    } else {
        Periodo_Estu = "Periodo - II";
    }


    $scope.data = {};

    dataImage = localStorage.getItem("imgData");

    if (dataImage === null) {
        $scope.data.ImageURI = "img/profile_icon.png";
    } else {
        $scope.data.ImageURI = dataImage;
    }  

    $scope.obtenerFoto = function (){

         navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { 

             quality: 100,
             destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
             sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY

         });

    };

    function onSuccess(imageURI) {

        var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
        image.src = imageURI;
        localStorage.setItem("imgData", imageURI);

    }

    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }

}
```